# speech-recognition is too slow

Tags: python, speech-recognition

Too much time is spent for speech recognition. The recognition takes over 15 minutes to run.

How can I make the speech recognition faster? Here's my code:

```
def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query= r.recognize_google(audio,language= 'en-in')
        print(f"user said: {query}\n")
    except Exception as e:
        speak("Miss stark couldn't recognize what you said, speak once more.")
        print("Miss stark couldn't recognize what you said, speak once more.")
        query=None

    return query
```

Comment: Is there a time lag in listening voice or recognizing it? In the second case, its an issue of Google Speech engine, try another engine

Comment: time lag, delay

Comment: Yea, what cause the time lag? Listening or recognizing?

Comment: recognizing the speech

Comment: I have tried the Microsoft bing as well as IBM one as well. still having the same problem

Comment: Then try increasing threshold frequency, speaking louder etc.

Comment: Can you check your internet speed and http logs for the REST API calls.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code more frequently using these lines added to your.

```
  def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query= r.recognize_google(audio,language= 'en-in')
        print(f"user said: {query}\n")
    except Exception as e:
        speak("Miss stark couldn't recognize what you said, speak once more.")
        print("Miss stark couldn't recognize what you said, speak once more.")
        return None
    return query
```

And if this not works check your internet connection speed, because SpeechRecognition works through internet connection.